# How to write a program to get all methods to get 2016 using numbers from 9 to 1?

Tags: python, algorithm, math

You can add any operator(including parentheses and + - * / ** ) between 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1.
For example,
`98*76-5432*1=2016`
`9*8*7*(6+5-4-3)*(2-1)=2016`

I wrote a programme like this

```
from __future__ import division
s = ['+','-','*','/','','(',')']

def calc(s):
    a=s.split()
    return eval(''.join(a))
a=['','9','','8','','7','','6','','5','','4','','3','','2','','1.','']

def test(tmp):
    if tmp == 20:
        try:
            z = eval(''.join(a))
            if z == 2016:
                print ''.join(a)
        except:
            pass
        return
    for i in s:
        #print a
        a[tmp] = i
        test(tmp+2)
for j in s:
    a[0] = j
    test(2)
```

But it is not right, because there can be multiple operators exist between numbers.

Comment: Unless I am misunderstanding what you are trying to accomplish, it is impossible to get all possible equations that equal 2016 because there are infinitely many solutions.

Comment: You can add and then subtract one from the end of your sequence of operations indefinitely.

Comment: @jYeager: I think you're misunderstanding. IIUC, there are only the digits 9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1 to be used, and only in that order; there are a finite number of distinct values that can be generated from those digits and the listed operations.

Comment: @DSM I see what you are saying. I overlooked that constraint.

Comment: Why don't you simply brute force it ? I've done some rough maths and it seems to have maximum 23059204 possible sequences of operators which you can apply. You can calculate them in reasonable time and filter out the ones which equate to 2016.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a well known trick to questions that involve constructing arithmetic expressions with brackets: often it's easier to use reverse polish notation instead.

Here's code that does this.

```
# Compute "a op b", returning None if the result
# is no good (eg: 9/0 or too big).
def do_op(a, op, b):
    if op == '+':
        return a + b
    if op == '-':
        return a - b
    if op == '*':
        return a * b
    if op == '/':
        if b == 0 or a % b != 0:
            return None
        return a // b
    if op == '**':
        # Disallow arguments that would result
        # in fractions or huge numbers, being careful
        # to allow valid results.
        if a == 1:
            return a
        if a == -1:
            return -1 if b % 2 else 1
        if a == 0 and b == 0:
            return None
        if b < 0 or b > 20 or a > 10000 or a < -10000:
            return None
        return a ** b
    assert False

# Generates expressions that result in the given target.
# ops is the a record of the operations applied so far,
# stack is the evaluation stack, and num is the first
# digit that we've not pushed yet.
def sums(ops, stack, num, target):
    if not num and len(stack) == 1:
        if stack[0] == target:
            yield ops
        return

    # If num is 7, say, try pushing 7, 76, 765, 7654, ..., 7654321.
    k = num
    for i in xrange(num, 0, -1):
        for s in sums(ops + [k], stack + [k], i-1, target):
            yield s
        k = 10 * k + (i - 1)

    # If we've less that 2 things on the stack, we can't apply
    # any operations.
    if len(stack) < 2:
        return

    # Try each of the possible ops in turn.
    for op in ['+', '-', '*', '/', '**']:
        result = do_op(stack[-2], op, stack[-1])
        if result is None:
            continue
        for s in sums(ops + [op], stack[:-2] + [result], num, target):
            yield s


# Convert a list of operations that represent an expression in RPN
# into infix notation. Every operation is bracketed, even when
# that's redundant.
def to_infix(ops):
    stack = []
    for p in ops:
        if isinstance(p, int):
            stack = stack + [p]
        else:
            stack = stack[:-2] + ['(%s%s%s)' % (stack[-2], p, stack[-1])]

    assert len(stack) == 1
    return stack[0]

# Starting with an empty stack (and no operations), with 9 as the first
# unused digit, generate all expressions that evaluate to 2016.
for s in sums([], [], 9, 2016):
    print to_infix(s)
```

It takes a few minutes to run, but there's a lot (more than 25000) of valid expressions that evaluate to 2016.

My favorite is (((98*76)-5432)*1).